# How to send response using "new Response" or "Response::factory()" in Kohana 3.1?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

The examples I see are suggesting the use like this:

```
$response = new Response();
echo $response->body($view)->send_headers()->body();
```

But if I have the following code

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers('Content-Type', 'application/json');
echo $response->body($view)->send_headers()->body();
```

it sends the output allright, but it is in HTML format, not JSON.

Whats the valid way to send a new Response along with headers then? I am using Kohana 3.1 with php 5.3

Edit:

Before you start thinking what a fool I am for not using `$this->response->body(<blah here>);`, let me clarify that I know how to use the controller's response object... That is not what I am looking for... I want to send a response entirely from a static function that is not anywhere near a controller in the function call stack :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after scratching my head and attempting many solutions, I decided to use this:

`Request::initial()->response()

->body($view)

->headers('Content-type','application/json');`

Works from anywhere unless you write `exit` somewhere in the flow.

Comment: This actually is not a direct answer to your original question.

Comment: The code in question doesn't work because it is an "echo", so it wasn't working as it should. The code in accepted answer works because its actually rendering the result using the response object and not "echo"ing to the browser.

Comment: I have meant this:
"I want to send a response entirely from a static function that is not anywhere near a controller in the function call stack :)"

When you use `Request::initial()->response()` you are actually using the response object from the initial request which was already executed (or being executed) and thus going through the conroller, actions and stuff.

Comment: Exactly my point :) I didn't know there exists such a `Request::initial()->response()` which comes from the original controller... Finding that was my eureka moment :D

Answer (score 1):

Still new to Kohana but here's how I did it and it seems to work fine:

```
$this->response->headers('Content-type','application/json; charset='.Kohana::$charset);
$this->response->body(json_encode( $data_array ));
```

I'm thinkin charset is optional... hope this helps.